# Finding an file through a path and excute it using the terminal In Linux with C language

Tags: linux, string, terminal, find, strtok

Im trying to write a program that will print in while loop, to enter a location,if the location exists on the path execute it,if not write no file found,Moreover if the user enter leave it exits the program.

I tried to use strok function since I see the ":" is separating between the folders. once i found the path I should use fork and hten execv and wait until the process finish.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
    char *p;
    int i = 0;
    const char s[2] = ":";
    char command[400];
    char *tok_arr[200];
    char *temp;

    printf("\nlets start\n");
    p = getenv("PATH");

    /* 
       Here should be the strtok..which does not work for me... 
    */

    /* 
       After that should I do one more while in order to get all the folders of getenv seperated with " : ". ? 
    */

    do {
    /* 
       Here I should print what app/file the user would like to use
       if I can found it than excute it,otherwise print a message that
       file not found.
       untill the user prints leave.
    */
    while(strcmp(command,leave) == 1);  
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `execvp`?

Comment: can't unfortunately ...@William pursell